# Hide white space after adding expandable rows in an angular material table

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to make the rows of my table expandable, but in the space below my starting row, once the expandable row has been added, this annoying space appears:

[This is the space i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trcd1.png)

Now i need to hide this space. How can i do it?

Comment: Please share the code by which we can see the proper issue/structure and then can try to help. Without code we can't do anything.

Comment: Its nothing other than default padding and margin's applied by expandable title and body parts. You can easily override them by inspecting and apply custom css properties with !important attribute to it.